# Unable to validate response headers from a REST API using Karate

Tags: rest, testing, karate

I have a simple REST API that allows to POST resources in a given endpoint, and I want to validate that the response headers are set correctly. I have defined the following feature, which inserts a bunch of users in the database:

```
  Scenario Outline: Creating a bunch of new users when the database is empty
    Given header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And request __row
    When method post
    Then status 201
    * match header Content-Type == 'application/json'
    * match header Location == 'http://localhost:8080/users/'+response.id

    Examples:
      | users |
```

Users are inserted correctly, and in console I can see the following response headers:

```
1 < 201
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 14:06:31 GMT
1 < Keep-Alive: timeout=60
1 < Location: http://localhost:8080/users/user1@test.com
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But each time I try to run this test, I get the same response:

```
path: $['Content-Type'][0], actual: null, expected: 'application/json', reason: actual json-path does not exist
```

Comment: can you please try the new RC version where this should work better: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me on 0.9.6

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* method get
* match header Content-Type == 'application/json'
```

But as I mentioned in my comment, please try the 1.0 / RC version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

As we are focusing efforts on that.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying version 0.9.6 (on windows), but with version 0.9.9.RC4 everything works correctly